# Struggling with importing QuantumCircuit from qiskit

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, qiskit

ImportError: cannot import name 'QuantumCircuit' from partially initialized module 'qiskit' (most likely due to a circular import)

```py
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
qc = QuantumCircuit
```

gives error message

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'QuantumCircuit' from partially initialized 
module 'qiskit' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a new-line (or semi-column) missing.

```py
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
qc = QuantumCircuit
```

Or

```py
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit; qc = QuantumCircuit
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Ensure that Qiskit is properly installed.
`pip install --upgrade qiskit`

Then use this code.

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit

qc = QuantumCircuit(2, 2)

qc.h(0)
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.measure([0, 1], [0, 1])
```

This is the sample code that I used for testing your code.